# appendChild for ahref won't appear when assigning to innerText

Tags: innertext

I'm trying to create a new link element (a href). In my console.log it shows the format properly/perfect but in the page itself it only shows the URL without hyperlink and not the Text with a hyperlink.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var even = 0;
  $(".entitylist.entity-grid").on("loaded", function() {
    $(this).children(".view-grid")
      .find("tr[data-    entity='knowledgearticle']").each(function(i, e) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        var linkText = document.createTextNode($(this).data("name"));
        var value = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[even].getAttribute('data-value');
        a.appendChild(linkText);
        a.title = $(this).data("name");
        a.href = "/knowledgebase/article/" + value;
        console.log(document.body.appendChild(a)); //show me the     constructed/final ahref
        document.getElementsByTagName("td")[even + 1].innerText = document.body.appendChild(a);
        document.getElementsByTagName("td")[even + 1].innerHTML = document.body.appendChild(a);
        even = even + 2;
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you,
Rome

Comment: The link didn't appear here in my question so I'm posting it again

Comment: a title="How to Reallocate Payment" href="https://samplelink.com">How to Reallocate Payment</a

Comment: You could add some more details, including code. Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you, Rainer. I have edited my post.

Comment: Why this space `"tr[data-    entity='knowledgearticle']"` there?

Comment: I have formatted your code however it would be easier to obtain a great answer if the HTML was included